# LINQ Average TimeSpan?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, datetime

I have a database table that contains entries for start time and end time of an event. I would like to take those entries and find the average length of an event. The subtraction is no problem. However, when I try to get the average value, the compiler complains.

Here is my current LINQ query:

```
public TimeSpan? getAverageTime()
    {
        return (from EventTime in db.EventTimes
                where EventTime.EventTimesID > 0
                select (EventTime.TimeEnd - EventTime.TimeStart)).Average();
    }
```

I also tried .Sum() and .Aggregate() so that I could have something to work with, but none are accepted.

What is the best method for accomplishing my goal?

Comment: How exactly does the compiler complain?

Comment: What's the compiler error you get?

Comment: System.LINQ.IQueryable<TimeSpan?> Does not contain a definition for 'Average'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you have to use a SqlMethods.DateDiff in linq2sql statement (DATEDIFF function if SQL):

```
public int getAverageTime()
    {
        return (from EventTime in db.EventTimes
                where EventTime.EventTimesID > 0
                select (SqlMethods.DateDiffMinute(EventTime.TimeStart, EventTime.TimeEnd)).Average();
    }
```

Comment: You are correct! This works great. The only change necessary is that TimeEnd comes first.

Answer (score 6):

`Average` doesn't work with `TimeSpan` values, which are what you get when you subtract two `DateTime` values.  Try averaging `(EventTime.TimeEnd - EventTime.TimeStart).TotalMilliseconds` then converting that back to a TimeSpan afterward.

Comment: Excellent. This one worked for me. Had a list of TimeSpan objects to avergae out, and your suggestion worked: TimeSpan avg = new TimeSpan(TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond * (long)System.Math.Round(ProcessElementTimes.Select(time => time.TotalMilliseconds).Average(), 0));

Comment: @David: You could simplify it to `TimeSpan.FromTicks(ProcessElementTimes.Average(x => x.Ticks);` Besides, do you really need the rounding? If you do, rounding the result instead of each value would be more precise.

Answer (score -2):

```
var avg=(from t in array select (t.endtime.Ticks-t-starttime.Ticks)).Average();
Console.Write(new DateTime((long)avg).TimeOfDay);
```