# How can I average a DateTime field with a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a database that has the following records in a DateTime field:

```
2012-04-13 08:31:00.000
2012-04-12 07:53:00.000
2012-04-11 07:59:00.000
2012-04-10 08:16:00.000
2012-04-09 15:11:00.000
2012-04-08 08:28:00.000
2012-04-06 08:26:00.000
```

I want to run a linq to sql query to get the average time from the records above. I tried the following:

```
(From o In MYDATA Select o.SleepTo).Average()
```

Since "SleepTo" is a datetime field I get an error on Average(). If I was trying to get the average of say an integer, the above linq query works.

What do I need to do to get it to work for datetimes?

Comment: Do you have a SleepFrom value by any chance?

Comment: I'd try creating my own extension method for that.

Answer (score 10):

Internally, every DateTime is really stored as a number of ticks.  The `Ticks` property of a DateTime is defined as the "number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001."  (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx)

You can convert the DateTimes to ticks, then average, then convert back to a datetime.

```
var averageTicks = (long) dates.Select(d => d.Ticks).Average();
var averageDate = new DateTime(averageTicks);
```

Using your data structures and formatting, it would look like this:

```
var averageTicks = (long)(from o in MYDATA select o.SleepTo.Ticks).Average();
var averageDate = new DateTime(averageTicks);
```

If you want to get the average time of each SleepTo value (ignoring the Date component), you can get the ticks of just the time:

```
var averageTicks = (long)(from o in MYDATA select o.SleepTo.TimeOfDay.Ticks).Average();
var averageTime = new TimeSpan(averageTicks);
```

Comment: This will not give the desired answer, since the question relates to the average *time* for SleepTo, not the average DateTime. I would seriously recommend converting SleepTo into TimeSpan since midnight (or even Ticks since midnight) and then averaging that, otherwise all answers are wrong.

Comment: The code sample and last question in Jade's original post led me to believe that he or she was asking for help averaging `DateTime`s.  Based on your suggestion, @yamen, I added a new snippet for averaging just the time components. Thanks!

Comment: With a lot of `Ticks` it seems like `.Average(...)` throws an overflow exception. I assume it's trying to sum all of the long values? (into a double it seems)

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple extensions methods that can help with this... There is a core problem where if you have a lot of DateTimes in a list the LINQ average of a the ticks (`long` vars) will overflow.

```
    public static long Average(this IEnumerable<long> longs)
    {
        long count = longs.Count();
        long mean = 0;
        foreach (var val in longs)
        {
            mean += val / count;
        }
        return mean;
    }

    public static DateTime Average(this IEnumerable<DateTime> dates)
    {
        return new DateTime(dates.Select(x => x.Ticks).Average());
    }
```

Comment: +1. Thanks. This is an improvement on the accepted answer, when the number of items is sufficiently large.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Nice improvement!

Comment: I think this may accumulate an error since you are using an integer division for val/count. Try using your Average with new[] { 3l, 5l, 7l } - the correct average is 5, you get 4. I believe you should be using doubles for the intermediate math.  I also prefer using Linq when extending Linq because it's harder to understand :) public static long Average(this IEnumerable<long> longs) {
  var count = longs.Count();

  return (long)(longs.Aggregate(0.0, (r, l) => r += (double)l / count)); }

Comment: At the precision level of `Tick` that this is averaging, a minor rounding error in the average may not matter very much. I can't say for certain, though! There may be additional precision loss when casting back and forth to `double`.

Answer (score 1):

The database LINQ provider doesn't seem to understand how to do averages on absolute dates. Which, if you think about it, makes sense (average is a sum divided by a count - what is the sum?).

So, if you're not able to run the following:

`(From o In MYDATA Select o.SleepTo).Sum()`

Then you won't be able to do `.Average()` also.

Since what you want is actually the average *time* of SleepTo, you need to get just the time component of the date as a TimeSpan (time minus midnight perhaps) and average that. Do you by any chance have `SleepFrom`?

In the meantime, you might find this post enlightening: [LINQ Average TimeSpan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086087/linq-average-timespan)

Comment: I tried Sum but it doesn't like dates either. The data in my sample are the times I woke up. I'm trying to get the average time that I woke up.

Comment: That's my point, sum won't work - therefore average won't work either. Your best best is to strip out the day component and just get the time. Turn that into a timespan from midnight and then you can get average. This will give you your average wake time (AM). See the link I posted.

Comment: Updated my answer to ask for information regarding whether you have `SleepFrom` (which makes everything simple) or if you want just time since midnight? That is, do you want to know the average time at which you wake up, or the average amount you sleep?